# AJAX POST PHP NOT ACCEPTING?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I understand this has been asked multiple times but I am unsure why this isn't working!

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['testingajax'])) {
    echo "Received";
} else {
    echo "Not received";
}
?>

<button onclick = 'sendAjax()'>click me</button>

<script>
function sendAjax() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {
      testingajax: 2
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("AJAX POST SENT");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
      handle.innerText = 'Error: ' + jqXHR.status;
    }
  });
}
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

This is what shows after clicking the button, it should say Received
[image]

I have tried changing the URL to `http://localhost/TESTINGPLANNER/src/test.php` and `./test.php` but no luck. Also, I have changed `testingajax: 2` to `'testingajax': 2`. 
From the network screenshot it seems like AJAX it is working so I am not sure where the issue is.

Comment: So what isn't working? What is `data` when logged in the ajax success? The fact the success handler fires is a good sign

Comment: What is not working is that it is not printing the PHP echo

Comment: `Not received` is there on the initial load regardless, no? You need to update the DOM after AJAX fires. PHP loads first, so `if(isset($_POST['testingajax'])) {` is always fired first and false

Comment: Can you also add the response headers?

Comment: @user3783243 and you are  correct but the issue is my PHP does not go into the if statement when I send the POST request, I tried updating a PHP variable after the ajax post and it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not run the PHP code in another file? Cus there's no way to run PHP code in that file again after it's loaded.

Comment: Your `success` function does nothing to DOM to change it. How do you know it `doesnt work`? Put `received`/`not received` in an named element and update it on success.

Comment: Your code runs on my test system, sending a message to the server and the server responds. The message AJAX POST SENT appears in the console log. Nothing else happens because you're not asking for anything more.